# Add underline to Bootstrap's Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a design in inkscape which I now want to start building in HTML using the bootstrap framework.

However, I am finding it a bit frustrating/lost trying to add a underline to the panel heading.

The code in bootstrap is this particular bit just to show what panel component I am referring to:

```
<section class="panel panel-primary">
  <header class="panel-heading">
   <h5 class="panel-title">Panel title</h5>
  </header>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <p>Panel content</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

This displays the default bootstrap panel like so:

[image]

What I want to achieve is the following: (*please note I am only referring to the underline in the image below to style the panel to match the styling below I can do so don't worry about the full CSS I am fairly comfortable with it, it's just for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to add the underline to the default bootstrap panel component.*)

[image]

**Tl;Dr**
Just to be super clear ignore the different styling I can manage that just help me understand how to add the underline to the panel heading.

**EDIT**

Thank you so much guys this means the world to me.
It works! See below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is add a custom style for `.panel-body` to have a top margin and a top border.

```
.panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid #337ab7;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Here's a working codepen for you to review. http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/KgOGvq

Comment: sir thank you so much! Just had to think outside the box I was so fixated on the panel header I completely forgot I have a panel body!

I will select your answer in a moment

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ZpgqXr?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<section class="panel panel-primary">
  <header class="panel-heading">
   <h5 class="panel-title">Panel title</h5>
  </header>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <hr class="custom-separator" />
   <p>Panel content</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.panel { 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.custom-separator {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #428BCA;
  margin: -12px -15px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Dammit! This is equally as good!!!! I am so sorry I wish I could select both answers I feel so bad now.

Comment: @ErikThiart make sure you upvote the useful answers :)

Comment: Hello, I did I marked the first one as correct since it is correct, but this answer is equally as good and I love this method so I upvoted it.

Comment: I want to help both I feel so bad I am so sorry